# how do you understand javascript code that is not written by you

Tags: reverse-engineering

Suppose you have 200 pages of code. Or any amount. But it is not written by you. So as in javascript anything can be done anywhere. How do you read it and understand? To decode or reverse engineer. 
Any tools that help in the process?
In general i find reading anyone else code beside mine to be impossible unless if it is less than half page.

Comment: not even a minute passed and -1 rating wow -_-

Comment: how about actually bothering to answer

Comment: First, read the Faq. Questions vague as this one are not encouraged here. Second, use a good IDE. Third, practice by reading more code. Go lend a hand to Javascript projects in Github or something.

Comment: Ultimate way is DEBUG the Code !!!!!!! there is no TOOL is like Understand some one else code.

Comment: or something? that's no answer

Comment: the code that has been through google closure is specifically too alien like to understand.

Comment: +1. It's a real question: how to start working on code not written by you? I was once paid to do that on a large Matlab code, and as Bojan said, working through function calls is the right thing to do. Also, analyse all nontrivial data structures, as code is merely written to use data. Think "big" at first: what is the program supposed to do? What's the algorithm used? etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I typically do is follow the call-in logic from outer layers of code inward and instead of trying to grok thousands of lines of someones program, I try to figure out how the pieces I need to work on function.

You don't read code top-down like you read a book (pages?), you  follow calls (initially you can ignore class instantiation) from the outmost position inwards. JavaScript is not a nice language in this regard but still if a compiler/interpreter can read it, so can you.

It's important to write readable code, and as a professional you should, on a policy level, expect that from other people, but on a technical level, you need to be able to cut through the bushes.

Comment: make videos of you doing it :D

Comment: that would make some boring videos: 1) there's nothing fun (to watch) in analyzing code and 2) I'm a relatively slow programmer anyway.

Comment: Ok thanks :D now i that i think about it there would be lot of babbling.

Answer (score 0):

you need to understand functional programming, jquery etc., if you have any specific question on javascript. Post it here.

Comment: I know jquery, i dont think jquery is functional programming code. Reading a functional programming would be so easy though.